# Check if path/file exists dropbox api IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way to check if a file exists in Dropbox by searching for its name / path?? I don't seem to find any information on-line and the only idea I have is to try to download it using this method:

```
[self.restClient loadFile:filename3 intoPath:CommentPath];
```

and then see the result, but this method is not reliable. Is there a proper one?

Comment: See the [Dropbox docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/files#ios) and look at the section titled "List File in a Folder". See if your file is listed in the results.